# How to configure recovery.zookeeper.path.* params correctly?

Tags: apache-flink

I have **one** Zookeeper cluster and want to use it for several environments (staging, production, etc.)

How to configure `recovery.zookeeper.path.*` parameters in this case?

I see two possible ways:

```
recovery.zookeeper.path.root: /{{ env }}/flink
recovery.zookeeper.path.latch: /{{ env }}/leaderlatch
recovery.zookeeper.path.leader: /{{ env }}/leader
```

or

```
recovery.zookeeper.path.root: /{{ env }}/flink
recovery.zookeeper.path.latch: /leaderlatch
recovery.zookeeper.path.leader: /leader
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ZNodes which Flink creates (including the leader and latch nodes) in ZooKeeper are relative to `recovery.zookeeper.path.root`. Consequently, you only have to change the root path `recovery.zookeeper.path.root` to set up your cluster for a different environment.